# Abri um Form dentro de um Panel

Tags: delphi, delphi-10, delphi-berlin, delphi-tokyo

Vendo uma Pergunta aqui no [Stackoverflw](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) onde uma das resposta era para abrir o `Form` dentro de um `Tpanel`.

É possível abr um `Form` dentro de um `Tpanel`? E se positivo como se faz para abri um `Form` Dentro de um `Tpanel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Também pode utilizar este formato:

```
var
  vForm : TForm;
begin
  vForm        := TForm.Create(MeuPainel);
  vForm.Parent := MeuPainel;
  vForm.Left   := 0;
  vForm.Top    := 0;
  vForm.Height := MeuPainel.Height;
  vForm.Width  := MeuPainel.Width;
  vForm.Show;
```

Um diferencial é que existira a possibilidade de movimentar o Formulário (carregar ele na tela);

Ainda vale lembrar que precisa de um controle de Memória para isto.

Answer (score 1):

Sim podes. Basta indicares que o parent do teu Form é o painel que desejas. Algo como

```
//Criar nova instancia do form e mostrar num painel
f:=TFrmMeuForm.Create();
f.BorderStyle:=bsNone;
f.Align:=alClient;
f.Parent:=MeuPainel;
f.Visible:=true;
```

Comment: Que bacana, vou fazer testes com isso. 
É bem simples...

Comment: TFrmMeuForm.Create(); não vai gerar um erro de criação?

Comment: Era um exemplo de um form meu que tem um construtor assim.. tipicamente leva o Owner como parametro de entrada, é isso que se refere?

Comment: Na verdade ele obrigatoriamente precisa de um Owner, seja existe (criado) ou não. Isso vem da Classe `TForm`.